# The FileNameExtensionFilter constructor is linted as undefined

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Here is the issue which I am facing - see the code below:

```
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.Images", "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
```

I am getting the following linting error:

```
The constructor FileNameExtensionFilter(String, String, String, String, String) is undefined.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [FileNameExtensionFilter SE8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html) and [FileNameExtensionFilter SE7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)  the constructor should accept your usage attempt.

However, based on your error, I suspect you might be using [the SE6 version](https://translate.google.co.il/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html&prev=search) whose constructor uses a string array as a parameter.

Can you make sure you are using the SE7/SE8 version of the class?

Comment: But I am using Java SE 8

Comment: Check your IDE and make sure you are using the correct JDK/JRE in your project properties. I lost count on the amount of times I forgot to map a project of mine to the correct JDK path......